# Apache Zeppelin - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, apache-zeppelin

I am trying Apache zeppelin . I wanted to have highcharts. So I thought of using %html interpreter. I have done this

```
print("%html <h3> Hello World!! </h3>")
```

It perfectly works. Know I have the code for highcharts

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                    ['IE',       26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Chrome',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Safari',    8.5],
                    ['Opera',     6.2],
                    ['Others',   0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But How could I put both together. I tried searching for samples but no help. Kindly someone help.

Answer (score 4):

using %angular should be the easiest.

One prerequisite is the highcharts.js should be loaded into the page.

> It could loaded in the notebook with jQuery
>
> It could be loaded by simple modification in Zeppelin

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/zeppelin.git
cd zeppelin
mvn clean package -DskipTests

cd zeppelin-web
bower install highcharts -S
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Though it is very straight forward to using %angular to create a static chart. While there is a gap to convert from Spark model to Highcharts.

So I create a project try to fill this gap. [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) can be used in Zeppelin, spark-shell, or other spark application.

```
%spark
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._

highcharts(bank
  .series("x" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("balance")))
  .orderBy(col("age")).plot()
```

And got a chart [image]

Comment: is your highcharts library opened sourced ? It looks interesting.

Comment: not yet. I am polishing it. @eliasah can you comment on the latest interface? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530410/are-there-better-interface-to-add-highcharts-support-to-zeppelin

Comment: I just publish the library.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I test it without a licence.

Comment: Highcharts is free for None commercial usage https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts

Comment: I had to remove these two artifacts because they produce these errors: com.knockdata:spark-highcharts:0.6.4
 and net.liftweb:lift-json:2.0 produced these errors java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapper cannot be cast to scala.collection.MapLike and org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException.

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin also supports pluggable packages at run-time through the [Helium framework](https://zeppelin.apache.org/helium_packages.html).  There are a handful of highcharts charts with published packages.