# Are there better interface to add Highcharts support to Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, highcharts, apache-zeppelin

[Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) has good support for [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). While there is a gap between Scala and Javascript.

I am trying to add [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) support to Zeppelin to fill in this gap. The main goal is to plot it simply directly from [Spark DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html).

After couple round refactor, I come up with the following interface.

[github.com/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts)

Here are two options. **Which option is better?**

## Option A

This is an example to plot highcharts.

```
highcharts(bank,
  "marital",
  List("name" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("balance")), "orderBy" -> col("age")),
  new Title("Marital Job Average Balance").x(-20),
  new Subtitle("Source: Zeppelin Tutorial").x(-20),
  new XAxis("Age").typ("category"),
  new YAxis("Balance(¥)").plotLines(Map("value"->0, "width"->1)),
  new Tooltip().valueSuffix("¥"),
  new Legend().layout("vertical").align("right").verticalAlign("middle")
)
```

Here is the code without extra option.

```
highcharts(bank,
           "marital",
           List("name" -> "age", 
           "y" -> avg(col("balance")), 
           "orderBy" -> col("age")))
```

## Option B

I come up this option with inspiring by @honnix's answer. It has more syntactic sugar.

```
highcharts(bank).series("marital")
  .data("name" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("balance")))
  .orderBy(col("age"))
  .title(Title("Marital Job Average Balance").x(-20))
  .subtitle(Subtitle("Source: Zeppelin Tutorial").x(-20))
  .xAxis(XAxis("Age").typ("category"))
  .yAxis(YAxis("Balance(¥)").plotLines("value"->0, "width"->1))
  .tooltip(Tooltip().valueSuffix("¥"))
  .legend(Legend().layout("vertical").align("right").verticalAlign("middle"))
  .plot
```

A simple plot without option will be

```
highcharts(bank).series("marital")
  .data("name" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("balance")))
  .orderBy(col("age"))
  .plot
```

It will generate a chart here.

[image: Marital Job Average Balance]

Comment: To be honest, I've read it earlier and I'm still thinking about it. I'm still not very completely aware of what you are expecting as an answer. :)

Comment: I was writing something similar with R a couple of days ago. I'm thinking about smoothing, filtering out lines, focus (or zoom) You can't do that with ggplot2

Comment: @eliasah I add more detail to the question. I wanna to ask if it's general and simple enough. any way to improve it?

Comment: It's starting to become more opinion based. I wouldn't vote to close thought but somebody else will, I believe. I believe it's good enough to release as is but you might want to prepare for eventual changes or missing "features". It would be better to discuss this on your project's repo.

Comment: @eliasah thanks. we can discuss after I clean the codes up a bit.

Comment: @eliasah I put it in to https://github.com/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to have some kind of chaining methods to pass in those parameters, because putting a few lists together in one apply() method is a little bit hard to read.

Comment: Do you mean use class as parameter which has chain method?

Comment: It would be roughly the same as using setters. Something like highcharts(bank). seriesCol(...). colDefs(...). But anyway this is just syntactic sugar. I'm not familiar with highcharts, neither zeppelin.