# couldnot connect apache-zeppelin to highcharts error : value seriesCol is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, highcharts, apache-zeppelin

i am trying to connect zeppelin with highcharts..

```
%spark 
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts._ 
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts.model._ 
import sqlContext.implicits._

val Tokyo = Seq(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3,
18.3, 13.9, 9.6).map(("Tokyo", _))

val df = (Tokyo).toDF("city", "temperature")

df.show()

highcharts(df.seriesCol("city").series("y" -> col("temperature"))).plot()
```

which gives

```
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts.model._
import sqlContext.implicits._
Tokyo: Seq[(String, Double)] = List((Tokyo,7.0), (Tokyo,6.9), (Tokyo,9.5), (Tokyo,14.5), (Tokyo,18.2), (Tokyo,21.5), (Tokyo,25.2), (Tokyo,26.5), (Tokyo,23.3), (Tokyo,18.3), (Tokyo,13.9), (Tokyo,9.6))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [city: string, temperature: double]
+-----+-----------+
| city|temperature|
+-----+-----------+
|Tokyo|        7.0|
|Tokyo|        6.9|
|Tokyo|        9.5|
|Tokyo|       14.5|
|Tokyo|       18.2|
|Tokyo|       21.5|
|Tokyo|       25.2|
|Tokyo|       26.5|
|Tokyo|       23.3|
|Tokyo|       18.3|
|Tokyo|       13.9|
|Tokyo|        9.6|
+-----+-----------+
<console>:201: error: value seriesCol is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
              highcharts(df.seriesCol("city").series("y" -> col("temperature"))).plot()
```

i have added dependencies artifact in spark interpreter as  `com.knockdata:zeppelin-highcharts:0.2`

followed https://github.com/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts/blob/master/docs/DemoLineChart.md
and tried bank data using [Are there better interface to add Highcharts support to Zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530410/are-there-better-interface-to-add-highcharts-support-to-zeppelin) but getting

```
<console>:224: error: value series is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Bank]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value series'?
                .series("x" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("income")))
```

please help me where i am going wrong? what could be the problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame can be implicitly convert to SeriesHolder which has a function seriesCol. It was added in version 0.6.0.

```
df.seriesCol("city")
```

The error should related to use a wrong version of [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts). The sample code(doc) is correspond to version 0.6.0 (map directly to zeppelin version).

Use docker might be the easiest way. Or use a similar way like the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts/~/dockerfile/)

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts
```

Comment: i am using zeppelin 0.6.0 only. they said `If you wanna run on your existing zeppelin, follow Use In Zeppelin.` , do i need to use docker again? and why bank data is not working?

Answer (score 0):

i changed the dependencies artifact in spark interpreter `com.knockdata:zeppelin-highcharts:0.2` to `com.knockdata:zeppelin-highcharts:0.6.0` to solve the problem.. but bank data problem still exist.. any help on this?

```
%spark
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts.model._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val bankText = sc.textFile("/home/priyanka/Downloads/bank-data.csv")

case class Bank(age:Integer, region:String, income : Float, married : String, children : Integer, car:String, save_act:String, current_act : String, mortgage : String, pep : String)

// split each line, filter out header (starts with "age"), and map it into Bank case class  
val bank = bankText.map(s=>s.split(",")).filter(s=>s(0)!="age").map(
    s=>Bank(s(0).toInt, 
            s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(2).replaceAll("\"", "").toFloat,
            s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(4).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt,
            s(5).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(6).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(7).replaceAll("\"", ""),      
            s(8).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(9).replaceAll("\"", "")
        )
)

// convert to DataFrame and create temporal table
bank.toDF().registerTempTable("bank")

highcharts(bank.series("x" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("income"))).orderBy(col("age"))).plot()
```

which gives

```
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.zeppelin.highcharts.model._
import sqlContext.implicits._
bankText: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[49] at textFile at <console>:62
defined class Bank
bank: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Bank] = MapPartitionsRDD[52] at map at <console>:66
<console>:70: error: value series is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Bank]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value series'?
                .series("x" -> "age", "y" -> avg(col("income")))
                 ^
```

thank you

Comment: Thanks very much for use it. I am the author. That was related to version issue. Use zeppelin-highcart:0.6.0 on zeppelin 0.6. (The previous doc was said zeppelin-highcharts:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT, the interface was changed. I have correct the doc)

Comment: thanks great.. thank you for giving this :).. any idea what is going wrong with reading from a file? bank data ? some clashes between `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` and `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`?

Comment: bank need be a DataFrame. Move the `toDF()` to end of bank define